# Will `function` produce an instance of an ES6 Class (Babel)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-class

Consider the following ES6 (to be transpiled by Babel):

```
class A {};

class B extends A {};

...

function isAnA(func) {
  // Return true if func will produce an A or subclass of A (e.g. B).
}

...

isAnA(B); // should return true
```

What is a valid way to code `isAnA()` to work without creating an instance of `func`?

`is-class` on npm requires running a `toString()` on the function which seems unwieldy.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Impossible if `func == function() { return new B(); }`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `prototype` object of the class B .

```
    function isAnA(func) {
     return func.prototype instanceof A;     
    }
```

```js
    class A {}

    class B extends A{}
    class C extends B{}

    function isAnA(func) {
     return func.prototype instanceof A;     
    }

    console.log(`B ? `,isAnA(B))
    console.log(`C ? `,isAnA(C))
```

Comment: But the prototype is not yet an instance, right? It doesn't become an instance until you call new.

Comment: To solve `isAnA(A)`, you'll either need to do `Object.create(func.prototype) instanceof A`, or `func.prototype instanceof A || func.prototype === A.prototype`

Comment: @JeffM: I did :) Thank you. Fixed by deleting the comment.

Comment: @JoshJ: *"It doesn't become an instance until you call new."* The prototype is an object. It doesn't become anything, it already exists.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks @FelixKling.